# Update Variable Values, Same MySQL query in Different ways

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I want to transform my query into a more readable shape
I want to know that what difference does it makes if I use a

MySQL Query in this way:

```
$query3 = "update users set mykey='".$val2."' where userid='$val3'";
```

Or this way:

```
$query3 = "update users set mykey='$val2' where userid='$val3'";
```

Or this way

```
$query3 = "update users set mykey=$val2 where userid=$val3 ";
```

I am pretty sure that If I'll use the last method the values which contain spaces will result in an error. But what about the 1st and 2nd?

Help will

Comment: there is no difference between 1st and 2nd queries...so there is no difference in which you should use...

Comment: sounds like you must read about [code injection](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_nf=1&tok=t09TKWnibZx_sTqzKt81lQ&cp=11&gs_id=kj&xhr=t&q=sql+code+injection&pf=p&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=sql+code+in&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=3a81358a6f75c627&biw=1440&bih=779) first

Comment: @LuisSiquot How do you come to that conclusion? There is no indication that `$val2` or `$val3` are anything but derived inside his own code.

Comment: @Fluffeh for the same content of $val2 and $val3 the 2nd and 3th options are not interchangebles, that makes me think that Absar is not taking in mind sql injection, and he is just raw concatenating the content.  It is only a warning, is what all of us do allways here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes down to personal preference, but I find the following would be the easiest to read:

```
$query3 = "update users set mykey='".$val2."' where userid='".$val3."'";
```

This is merely due to syntax highlighting in my IDE by showing strings and variables in a different format.

Comment: Fine, But there is a dumb question,
Do you think that if I use like this, (first variable with first way, 2nd with 2nd way)


`update users set mykey='".$val2."' where userid='$val3'"`

There will be no error?

Comment: @AbsarAkram As long as you use `"` to enclose the string as a whole, it won't error out - but you can only parse variables inside `"` quotes. Single quotes won't work.

Comment: @MihaiIorga Yeah, I meant the entire string is enclosed in `"` not single: `$qry="something.... $var"` will work, `$qry='something.... $var'` will not work :)

Comment: @fluffeh I am a junior and confused in your discussion, Can you finally tell that either the following query will work or not,

`$query = "update users set mykey='$val2' where userid='$val3'";`

You guys are really monsters,

Comment: And this one
`"update users set mykey='".$val2."' where userid='$val3'"`

Comment: @AbsarAkram Yes, it will also work fine :) Only your thrid query has the potential to fail if your variables are strings as they are not encapsulated in quotes.

Comment: @fluffeh  I was going to post new question but then though I've you here...

Please tell me that these two queries having same name are on a page and execute 2nd after the first, Will this work properly?

1st:

`$query3 = "update users set mykey='".$val2."' where userid='$val3'";
$result3=mysql_query($query3);`


2nd:

`$query3 = "SELECT * FROM `users` where userid='$val3'";
$result3=mysql_query($query3);
$row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);`

Comment: @AbsarAkram Yeah, you have replaced the contents of the variable, so you can re-use it in a different query without any hassles.

Comment: please @Fluffeh, drop a line here to Absar, to let him know that $valX can have any value if they where previously ESCAPED. to avoid sql injection

Comment: @AbsarAkram Luis is correct to point out that using a prepared statement is much safer than using variables directly in a query. I use [PDO](http://au2.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) myself and find that [prepared statements](http://au2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) are the safest way to use variables in database interaction.

Comment: @fluffeh and Luis Siquot, Thank You sincere guyx!  :)

Answer (score 2):

1. It's the more elegant way, you can read the code in any highlighter software or application.
2. It's OK, no highlight, but the main string must be with double quotes `"`
3. It's not OK because if your variable has 2 words it will break your query.

as a side note: remember always to escape your variables if you are still using `mysql_*` functions, because none of the answers are valid without proper escape.

Comment: I like your style, same personal preference :)